# How to start an automatic slideshow of images in Gallery?

Tags: gallery, photos

Using Gallery I have done a slide show of images. Now I need to automatic slideshow of images. When I click "play" button it should automatically scroll and when I click pause it should stop scrolling. How is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Click *Gallery* > Click any folder, e.g. *Camera* > Click any photo

Now the photo is shown full screen.

Click *Slideshow* in the left-down of screen. (It may be hidden. Touch the screen to let it show.)

(after a while)

Touch the screen to stop rolling.